# Matrix exponential of a 2x2 matrix composed of a antihermitian matrix and a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

As per the title, I'd like to calculate the exponential of a matrix which has an antihermitian component and a symmetric component (although this fact may not be useful). More specifically

$$\mathbf{M}=\begin{pmatrix}ia&b+ic\\b+ic&id\end{pmatrix}$$

I have in front of me the solutions for the case that $b = 0$ (antihermitian) and the case for $a,c,d = 0$ (symmetric), but not for $\mathbf M$. Does anyone know of a convenient form for calculating this?

Perhaps I should elaborate; computing by various methods is not a problem, but I'm wondering if there is a convenient set of formulae for this as there are for, say, the real case. To further elaborate, I've used a formula for convenience in the case of $\exp (-i\mathbf{H}t)$, where $\mathbf{H}t$ is Hermitian many times to solve the Schrödinger equation. This is really just to expedite calculations, since it's a waste of my time to do it the long way. I'm now working with dissipative systems a lot, and one way to handle them is with what is referred to as a *non-hermitian Hamiltonian*. That's where this question comes in.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for the cleanup. I didn't realise that you could enter maths directly (closes LaTeXiT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always perform a Schur decomposition on $\mathbf M$, $\mathbf M=\mathbf Q\mathbf T\mathbf Q^\ast$, where $\mathbf T$ is upper triangular, $\mathbf Q$ is unitary, and ${}^\ast$ is the conjugate transpose. Then you can compute the exponential of a $2\times 2$ triangular matrix easily:

$$\exp\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\exp\,a&\frac{b}{a-c}(\exp\,a-\exp\,c)\\0&\exp\,c\end{pmatrix}$$

and then multiply the unitary factors to obtain the exponential of your original matrix.

Comment: I don't have the time to sit down with a pen and paper at the moment, but I have a sneaking suspicion that $Q$ will involve a matrix exponential...

Comment: Not really. You can Schur decompose $\mathbf M$ (with either a Givens or a Househilder transformation) even before you do any exponential evaluations.

Comment: I added some clarification into the question. I know how to solve a $2\times 2$ matrix exponential. That's not really the question. I want to know if there's some convenient way such as those for other types of $2\times 2$ matrix. If not, then I'll continue to do it the longer way. It would just make work go a little faster. ;)

Comment: So far as I can tell, [it's not very simple at all](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp%5B%7B%7BI*a%2C+b+%2B+I*c%7D%2C+%7Bb+%2B+I*c%2C+I*d%7D%7D%5D)... at the very least, Schur decomposition makes the computations easier.

Comment: Turns out Givens rotation is my usual starting point. Didn't know the name!

Comment: Oh well. Worth a shot in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bite the bullet and use the good ol' eigenvalue decomposition $M = VJV^{-1}$.
$$ e^M = Ve^JV^{-1}$$
Since your matrix $2\times 2$, this should not cause too much of a trouble.

Moreover, every nonhermitian(nonsymmetric) matrix can be decomposed into a Hermitian and anti-Hermitian (symmetric and anti-symmetric) part via
$$
S = \frac{M+M^*}{2}, A = \frac{M-M^*}{2}
$$
and $A+S = M$. Hence, there is not much of specialty. Your feeling about that fact is indeed correct. If this is not enough, you can [look for the alternative ways](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf) for which there are at least 18 more. :) Well, let say at least 17 more since J.M. also gave another method.